# OutOfMemoryError: java heap space when reading a 35MB xlsx file using Apache POI HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java

I am using Apache POI HSSFWorkbook to read a 35MB xlsx file with 15000 rows and 400 columns, the memory consumption is 3.06GB and an OutOfMemoryError: java heap space appears. Do you have any optimization suggestions?

```java
    public static ArrayList<List<String>> readWorkBook(InputStream in, int columnCount, int beginLine, boolean isXlsx) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Workbook xssfWorkbook;
        try {
            if (isXlsx) {
                xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
            } else {
                xssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(in);
            }
            for (int numSheet = 0; numSheet < xssfWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets(); numSheet++) {
                Sheet xssfSheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(numSheet);
                if (xssfSheet == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                for (int rowNum = beginLine; rowNum <= xssfSheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++) {
                    Row xssfRow = xssfSheet.getRow(rowNum);
                    if (xssfRow == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    ArrayList<String> curarr = new ArrayList<>();
                    int temp = 0;
                    for (int columnNum = 0; columnNum < columnCount; columnNum++) {
                        Cell cell = xssfRow.getCell(columnNum);
                        if (cell == null || Trim_str(getValue(cell)) == null) {
                            curarr.add("");
                            temp++;
                        } else {
                            curarr.add(Trim_str(getValue(cell)));
                        }
                    }
                    if (temp != columnCount) {
                        result.add(curarr);
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Try the SXSSWorkbook

Comment: I can use SXSSWorkbook to solve the OutOfMemoryError problem of exporting data, but the solution for reading data has not been found in SXSSWorkbook. Could you please provide an example？

Answer (score 0):

try use xlsx-streamer this api provide streamer method  to read xlsx(just support xlsx)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.monitorjbl</groupId>
  <artifactId>xlsx-streamer</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
Workbook wb = StreamingReader.builder().rowCacheSize(100).bufferSize(8192).open(is);
```